# How to extract object values and convert to spread/rest arguments?

Tags: typescript, requirejs

I want to generate TypeScript definitions for JavaScript code in Magento 2 or RequireJS to be more precise.

Example:

```js
// Generated
const modules = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  test: { nesttest: 'Nice' }
} as const;

// Module
define(['test', 'a', 'b', 'unknown'], function (test, a, b, UnKnown) {
  // test = { nesttest: 'Nice' }
  // a = 1
  // b = 2
  // UnKnown = any | unknown
});
```

This is what I have so far. It is only for TypeScript, but I know how to continue after this problem:

- The `trueCallback` should return the same values as the `pseudoCallback`

```js
  //---------------//
 //--- Modules ---//
//---------------//

const modules = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  test: { nestedtest: 'Nice' }
} as const



  //-------------------//
 //--- Definitions ---//
//-------------------//

function define<
  Mods extends typeof modules,
  Keys extends keyof Mods,
  Input extends ReadonlyArray<InputVal>,
  InputVal extends string,
  InputUnion extends Input[number],
  InputArr extends TuplifyUnion<InputUnion>,
  Values extends Mods[Keys],
  ValuesArr extends TuplifyUnion<Values>,
>(
  keys: Readonly<Input>,
  pseudoCallback: (...args: [Mods['test'], Mods['b'], Mods['a']]) => void,
  trueCallback: (...args: unknown[]) => void, // WHAT COMES HERE?
) {
  const obj = modules as Mods;
  const values = keys.map(key => {
    if (key in obj) {
      return obj[key as keyof Mods];
    }

    return undefined;
  });

  trueCallback(...values);
}



  //-------------//
 //--- Usage ---//
//-------------//

define(['test', 'b', 'a'], function (test, b, a) {
  test
  // ^?

  const nested = test.nestedtest
  nested
  // ^?

  b
  // ^?

  a
  // ^?

  // SHOULD BE LIKE THIS
}, function (test, b, a) {
  test
  // ^?

  b
  // ^?

  a
  // ^?

  // DOES NOT WORK
})



  //-------------//
 //--- Types ---//
//-------------//

// Converts Union To Array
type TuplifyUnion<
  T,
  L = LastOf<T>,
  N = [T] extends [never] ? true : false
> = true extends N
  ? []
  : Push<TuplifyUnion<Exclude<T, L>>, L>;

type LastOf<T> = UnionToIntersection<T extends any ? () => T : never> extends () => (infer R) ? R : never;

type Push<T extends any[], V> = [...T, V];

type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type ObjValueTuple<
  T extends any,
  KS extends Array<any> = TuplifyUnion<keyof T>,
  R extends Array<any> = []
> = KS extends [infer K, ...infer KT]
  ? ObjValueTuple<T, KT, [...R, T[K & keyof T]]>
  : R;

type Mutable<T> = {
  -readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}

type DeepMutable<T> = {
  -readonly [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? DeepMutable<T[K]> : T[K];
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?emitDecoratorMetadata=false&pretty=false&filetype=ts#code/ATD0oWi6d8CgySsAsgewCYFcA2BTAZ2GgXFgpgXgGN0A7QgF2AFss8jgBeYAb0TAAhgC5gARgA0ggEZiATNJA0xAZiXAmRJmL7B62-Ji3MxAcgByASxr4zwAL7wHw4nUZN4XweUp-SoIi+EMAAIvgAZlb0VkxWDMQB8MH+lNQR2PQ0cQzAmJHR+AA8ghiYxPgAHlr05ZoAngAO+OgRbBwEhBoA0vj1FdX4tcQA1n2taFhdggCS9I3YLFU1dQBK+EKYDLj1AIIATvtC9UVzC0wAakK4AHwaZ4tXuMDLQ3XM+9EA5vfziwCqMVyr2GwAeTAA2vRsKwZPh9gBdX7nA77F6DUEAFWwjVwVgi9UB8Xopz+TCJDDugie2C4ILqZUIEN6-SR1OutMIqPRK2I2Nx+MJQJJNKIVJuAApBGN+mJ1pttidwVSQI1CPhsFsAMLXXAyIQ0EZiCUAOjNQn2X0IYghjIhZhMTDMSMm5XtMmdkldTLMQmdCIAlDwbsAAG7oKyYDRMfa0nW4PUGo3AU3my3W4CZEb0dAAd3oEMDwbDEajSGAAHUABK7THALUAeVQAFEAMrAKvN1bNgD88CDAmUCRY6BkACseO0cJ1XN6ANyCdzMMMcri8GWEE2sISNCUy4uDkDAfEp-fRYCjscDwRH4D7fBMbD7egX8cQ-dCUbjNqMhEL29ODed4Pk+L6ZPkUQGJg-6OAGC6CDGca6vqhqpiaoaroQcHON4PjIKkEAIEg0DAP8hBCF8+AkFAZD4ak1AQYUEr2o6ZhemYHrsX6LoZFkOQvhKjpejIXpCNeICOnhwAAHp9ouw76IYmCTo6JoGMwRiSSA6laJgUmyV4IAyPpckgEIJmGeWrZVg2-wADKhMAABCzbAHZMzdK5mJVjMrbOF6vHZMSKZCcAInCOJmjaBZsgxWZcXlqEDZtsAFgNnWFYNqs3TOAGuEgCk-hEcEwCYk0XBJIVfjUOA9YMKG8JMMQFIvpi6DAKixzwEw5WlTieIEi1JQgJiGh2ZOdmfkwDYREUmIqqlk4QpiCI8m8xBQvgDWIsAPaaLGVFiBE1zqvAIa8IhVH0sQFiCHthaCGIAAK2CEAAFnN-WCkNzaVDQuCasUo1uTcdwg-BPXNG5U0zXN52kcKbVzFo+zqkFDBzWtoJCPQ9S7SmQbcCGdZiAY20htdBPFhK0QRPCwCrEGe2rMApNbfCEO9S972Y5TOP1IWXoXPDEJmiawMXH+XiQ1RLVI-QKNo-xRT-PDEr-FjdT8-je5iP8hMhuGkas4p21BpTEq68e9B02iMwGyWkZM2CJtk-C0u9Q246ivyBDDaVmvEPzPTtpTnUnPz8O+99wpFDKEzzRoLNh4cxxFJHS0Imdk7dKHGJ1BCtP090Xpi0XaLdCtd3AF7Y4+-1QNepXXqi2aqxepizLAAAZMA8dtCtCI3I9DOc1DqCLEIMh+-Nk6HhA94KvQOzABCT3W3336lQiYid09UuATLYT4PgjQT0wU8z-D8+L1sy94135799vu-MqtlOXvg2T4+Ep-n5fQM34hlft0A+QA)

Comment: Why can't you just use the same types as you did the first callback? I'm confused.

Comment: @kelly Because the modules and the define calls are dynamic (always different). I needed a short solution. See the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I created a type `Mods` that just holds `typeof modules`.

```
const modules = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  test: { nestedtest: 'Nice' }
} as const

type Mods = typeof modules
```

Let's just use a single generic type `K` to represent the `keys` as a tuple type.

```
function define<
  K extends (keyof Mods)[]
>(
  keys: [...K],
  /* ... */
) {
  /* ... */
}
```

For `trueCallback` we can map over the tuple `K` with a mapped type. For each index `I` we take `K[I]` and use it to index `Mods`.

```
function define<
  K extends (keyof Mods)[]
>(
  keys: [...K],
  trueCallback: (...args: { 
    [I in keyof K]: Mods[K[I] & keyof Mods] 
  }) => void
) {
  /* ... */
}
```

For the implementation of the function, we can use an `any` assertion when we call `trueCallback`. TypeScript can't really understand that `values` has the correct type to call `trueCallback`.

---

This leads to the following end result:

```
function define<
  K extends (keyof Mods)[]
>(
  keys: [...K],
  trueCallback: (...args: { 
    [I in keyof K]: Mods[K[I] & keyof Mods] 
  }) => void
) {
  const obj = modules as Mods;
  const values = keys.map(key => {
    if (key in obj) {
      return obj[key as keyof Mods];
    }

    return undefined;
  });

  trueCallback(...values as any);
}

define(['test', 'b', 'a'], function (test, b, a) {
  test 
  // ^?{ readonly nestedtest: "Nice"; }

  b
  // ^? 2

  a
  // ^? 1
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?emitDecoratorMetadata=false&pretty=false&filetype=ts#code/ATD0oWi6d8CgySsAsgewCYFcA2BTAZ2GgXFgpgXgGN0A7QgF2AFss8jgBeYAb0TAAhgC5gARgA0ggEZiATNJA0xAZiXAmRJmL7B62-Ji3MxAcgByASxr4zwAL7wHw4nUZN48JgE8ADvhoWMS8vgHoAGZsHASEXoLklEmkoIiJEMAAIvgRVvRWTFYMxCnw6cmU1BHY9DSFDMCYOXn4ADyCANLA%20AAeWvSYxAAUANb4PpFBgwCUANoAuvAAfEOCYz6EYrMAdLsd8xpMAE7Y%20ADCQri4MkI0I2JDu9tCRwDmm-zAgiCzAJLAeWA60m%20zEGEGsw6f3mwAAZEDxpNwYQYYIHNMeEtgAA3dBWTCSJDAADqAAkAIIAFWAZwA8qgAKIAZWApIZACUGQB%20eAYgTKYosdAyABWPGiOFirimhAA3IJ3MwcZdTiEERttqwhH5RuNMfxvgCorqfAD6MBhSK%20YaQEd8ExsEdzZbZutpcCosj5vKQCAnIa7Q6ncAak1cgZMD7HNN5YJjqcLlcbndHrtsSquEJiEJ6D4Y854glkBUIAgkNBgABVQhCV6BUrlZLUMMtIazMwmJhmQlmGTd4BmIRmA7Aaq1ermoadwkyQlCa0gTtF4AAPR5smXa68ICEm556PgQA)

Comment: You are the best! Is there a way I can contact you?